# slick grid filter for multiselect

Tags: slickgrid

[image]

I'm having a scenario in which a checkbox may be shown or hidden in the grid.multi select should not select the checkbox hidden row but,in my scenario it is selecting all the rows whether checkbox is persent or not.

Any filters to avoid this row to not get selected.?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `example-checkbox-row-select.html`. You should be using the 6pac repo on GitHub: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid (see slickgrid.net)

You need to tweak `function selectRows`, `function deSelectRows`, and `function handleHeaderClick` in the file `plugins/slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js`

Comment: Appreciate your concern..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get new version of "slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js" and while setting data to your grid add "not_multiselectable = Y" for the rows which are not be selected.

Need to customise the code, if you are using filter.

cheers..

Thanks for all your help..